# What happens when content + padding + border > width in box-sizing: border-box?

Tags: css

As I understand it, `box-sizing` has two values: `content-box` and `border-box`.

My question is: when we declare `box-sizing: border-box`, and the total width of content and padding and border are larger than the width that is declared for the element, how does the browser solve this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size of the content area will be clamped to zero in order to accommodate as much of the padding and borders as possible, the padding and borders then extend from this zero content area if necessary, and the actual contents, if any, will overflow the padding and/or border area. Note that only the content area is affected; the padding and borders will remain intact. From the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui-3/#box-sizing):

> The content width and height are calculated by subtracting the border and padding widths of the respective sides from the specified width and height properties. As the content width and height [cannot be negative](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property) ([CSS21], section 10.2), this computation is floored at 0.

In the following example, the specified width of each `.box` element is 20px, but the minimum width required by the padding and borders in `box-sizing: border-box` is 5 + 10 + 10 + 5 = 30px. The content width is clamped to zero and the used width of the element is 30px, not 20px, as shown by the `.control` element which is explicitly and exactly 30 pixels wide. The image, itself being much wider, overflows the element (but anything with a width greater than zero will overflow the element anyway). And since overflow takes place, the content may or may not be clipped according to the `overflow` property set for the element.

```css
.control {
  width: 30px;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: #000;
}

.box {
  width: 20px;
  margin: 1em 0;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box + .box {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="control"></div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Image">
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Image">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for nice answer with clearly example. I have studied nearly `overflow` attribute and apply to your example and see that it works as I wish. I want to ask: Does `overflow` attribute often make for this case ? (content overflow). thanks :)

Comment: Yes, if you have `overflow: hidden` for example it will clip the content where it touches the border, and if you have `overflow: auto` it will create scrollbars (although be aware that some browsers have trouble rendering scrollbars if there is not enough padding to accommodate them).

Comment: thanks for comment. I understand now :D Can you give a little code for demo about `overflow` in your answer for other users easily to learn ? If you don't bother, I can edit your answer to add another example :)